# Count the number of ordered Items

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB1 <- data.frame(orderItemID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
orderDate = c("1.1.12","1.1.12","1.1.12","1.1.12","1.1.12", "1.1.12","1.1.12","2.1.12","2.1.12","2.1.12"),  
itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),   
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

Expected outcome:

```
Numberoforderedproductstotal = c(5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2) 
Numberoforderedproductslastorder = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)
Numberoforderedproductsaverage = c(2.5 , 1.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5)
```

Hey guys,
it´s me again with a problem I´m not really able to solve: 
In the data set I have items with the same size or the same color, the same ItemID. Every registered user has his unique customerID.

I want to identify (count) the number of articles every user orderd:
1.in total till now ((sum up the number of all ordered Items)
2. At the last order(sum up the number of all ordered Items from last order for every user[the date today is for example the 15.1.12])
3.The average number of ordered items overall orders
I also want to add the results as new columns in my existing data set...

I tried it already with the "count" and "tally" function - and also "countrep" and aggregate: but none of it worked properly...

I forgot that I also wanted a fourth column with the number of orders!
expected output then:

```
numberoforders: c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: "Hey guys, it´s me again".. most of the us..dint know where were you last time .:P

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the formula for bullet 3

Comment: it´s the average number of ordered items per order per customer: In the example customer with ID 1 ordered 3Items on the 1.1.12 and 2Items on the 2.1.12 - makes an average of 2.5((3/2+2/2)); customer with ID 2 ordered on the 1.1.12 2Items and on the 2.1.12 1Item - makes an average of 1.5(2/2+1/2) per order. customer with ID3 ordered only once (on the 1.1.12) 2 items- so the average is 2 (2/1)

Comment: Please don't update the question on the fly. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the following code seem to achieve your desired output

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DB1)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, format = "%d.%m.%y")]
DB1[, `:=`(Numberoforderedproductstotal = .N,
           Numberoforderedproductslastorder = length(itemID[orderDate == max(orderDate)]),
           Numberoforderedproductsaverage = .N/length(unique(orderDate)),
           Numberoforders = length(unique(orderDate))), 
    by = customerID][]

#     orderItemID  orderDate itemID customerID Numberoforderedproductstotal Numberoforderedproductslastorder Numberoforderedproductsaverage Numberoforders
#  1:           1 2012-01-01      2          1                            5                                2                            2.5              2
#  2:           2 2012-01-01      3          2                            3                                1                            1.5              2
#  3:           3 2012-01-01      2          3                            2                                2                            2.0              1
#  4:           4 2012-01-01      5          1                            5                                2                            2.5              2
#  5:           5 2012-01-01     12          1                            5                                2                            2.5              2
#  6:           6 2012-01-01      4          3                            2                                2                            2.0              1
#  7:           7 2012-01-01      2          2                            3                                1                            1.5              2
#  8:           8 2012-01-02      3          2                            3                                1                            1.5              2
#  9:           9 2012-01-02      1          1                            5                                2                            2.5              2
# 10:          10 2012-01-02      5          1                            5                                2                            2.5              2
```

Comment: My sister told me that I forgot to add a comment for your work: I´m really sorry for that and I hope it´s not to late to say "Thank you" :) You guys helped me a lot already and I hope I can ask another question if there is one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `ave` from `base R`

```
with(DB1, ave(customerID, customerID, FUN=length))
# [1] 5 3 2 5 5 2 3 3 5 5
DB2 <- transform(DB1, date=as.Date(orderDate, '%d.%m.%Y'))
with(DB2, ave(as.numeric(date), customerID, FUN=function(x) sum(x ==max(x))))
 #[1] 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2

with(DB2, ave(as.numeric(date), customerID,
         FUN=function(x) sum(table(x))/length(unique(x))))
# [1] 2.5 1.5 2.0 2.5 2.5 2.0 1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5
```

Or using `dplyr` (`n_distinct` from @David Arenburg's comments)

```
library(dplyr)
res <- DB1%>% 
            group_by(customerID) %>% 
            mutate(orderDate=as.Date(orderDate, '%d.%m.%Y'), 
              Numberoforderedproductstotal=n(), 
              Numberoforderedproductslastorder= sum(orderDate==max(orderDate)), 
              Numberoforderedproductsaverage=n()/n_distinct(orderDate),
              Numberoforders= n_distinct(orderDate))

  as.data.frame(res)[-(1:4)]
 #   Numberoforderedproductstotal Numberoforderedproductslastorder
 #1                             5                                2
 #2                             3                                1
 #3                             2                                2
 #4                             5                                2
 #5                             5                                2
 #6                             2                                2
 #7                             3                                1
 #8                             3                                1
 #9                             5                                2
 #10                            5                                2
#    Numberoforderedproductsaverage Numberoforders
#1                             2.5              2
#2                             1.5              2
#3                             2.0              1
#4                             2.5              2
#5                             2.5              2
#6                             2.0              1
#7                             1.5              2
#8                             1.5              2
#9                             2.5              2
#10                            2.5              2
```