# Sum of last order and average cost over all orders

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
orderDate = c("1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14", "1.1.14","1.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14"),  
itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
price = c(29.90, 39.90, 29.90, 19.90, 49.90, 9.90, 29.90, 39.90, 14.90, 19.90),
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

Expected outcome:

```
orderValueOfLastOrder = c(34.80, 39.90, 39.80, 34.80, 34.80, 39.80, 39.90, 39.90, 34.80, 34.80) 
AverageValue = c(67.25, 54.85, 39.80, 67.25, 67.25, 39.80, 54.85, 54.85, 67.25, 67.25)
```

Hi,
I got a problem to solve in r for my boss, so I would be very pleased if you peeps help me :)
In the data set every order got its own id and every registered user has his unique customerID. Every customer can order items (with ItemIDs), which got specific prices.
I want to sum the prices for the orders, but I had 2 problems:
1. I wanted the value(sum) of the last order for every customer ((sum up the prices of all ordered Items from last order for every user[the date today is for example the 15.10.14])
2. The average price per order[for his orders] for every user
I also want to add the results as new columns in my existing data set...

I tried it already with:

```
DB1$orderValueOfLastOrder<- with(DB1, ave(as.numeric(DB1$orderDate), 
price, FUN = function(x) sum(x ==max(x))))
```

but it´s not working...

so can you please show me a way to do it with "ave" function[I prefer to do it with ave (if this is not possible I would be very happy with every other solution, too :) )

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: This looks [very familar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864167/count-the-number-of-ordered-items/)... Are you both working at the same place?

Comment: it´s my brother-we´re both working for the same boss :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple and efficient solution using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DB)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, format = "%d.%m.%y")]
DB[, `:=` (orderValueOfLastOrder  = sum(price[orderDate == max(orderDate)]),
           AverageValue = sum(price)/length(unique(orderDate))), by = customerID]
```

If you prefer to leave it in a `data.frame` format, just use `setDF(DB)` (you need `data.table` v 1.9.4>= for that) or alternatively `DB <- as.data.frame(DB)` (for older versions)

```
setDF(DB)[]
#    orderID  orderDate itemID price customerID orderValueOfLastOrder AverageValue
# 1        1 2014-01-01      2  29.9          1                  34.8        67.25
# 2        2 2014-01-01      3  39.9          2                  39.9        54.85
# 3        3 2014-01-01      2  29.9          3                  39.8        39.80
# 4        4 2014-01-01      5  19.9          1                  34.8        67.25
# 5        5 2014-01-01     12  49.9          1                  34.8        67.25
# 6        6 2014-01-01      4   9.9          3                  39.8        39.80
# 7        7 2014-01-01      2  29.9          2                  39.9        54.85
# 8        8 2014-01-02      3  39.9          2                  39.9        54.85
# 9        9 2014-01-02      1  14.9          1                  34.8        67.25
# 10      10 2014-01-02      5  19.9          1                  34.8        67.25
class(DB)
## [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: will talk to him tomorrow:so hope he´s going to give some feedback then :) Thanks for your help david!

Comment: can I even do it without data frame or data table?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: I copied that part (what my brother used) from the answers he gets for his question     "with(DB1, ave(customerID, customerID, FUN=length))
DB2 <- transform(DB1, date=as.Date(orderDate, '%d.%m.%Y'))
with(DB2, ave(as.numeric(date), customerID, FUN=function(x) sum(x ==max(x))))
with(DB2, ave(as.numeric(date), customerID,
         FUN=function(x) sum(table(x))/length(unique(x))))

Comment: This is still a data frame

Comment: Whats is the problem with using the `data.table` package? It is much more efficient than any other

Comment: I do not deny :D I think I need another R lesson :)

Comment: I tried it today with my data set: and it was not working properly- everytime I tried it it shows me an "NA" in all rows for orderDate and also an "NA" in every row in orderValueOfLastOrder:where is the problem?

Comment: Found the mistake already-it was a prblem with the format of the date:sorry for that:like my name, still an absolute beginner :)

Comment: but I have a further question: what does the symbol ":=" mean/do?

Comment: Its "assign by reference" in data table. I suggest you read a bit about data.table